# Adapt systemd-resolve command to resolvectl

Tags: bash, 22.04, dns, vpn

I upgraded my ubuntu to 22.04 and a script that routes the traffic of my work vpn is not working properly since it uses a systemd-resolve command.

*How I use the script:* I manually execute a script (vpn.sh) that connects me to the VPN, and that script calls another script (vpn_routes.sh, the one with the problem) that routes the traffic of certain online tools of the client through the VPN and allows the rest of the traffic to connect to the internet bypassing the VPN.
vpn_routes.sh uses "systemd-resolve" in the last line and ubuntu 22.04 doesn't use that anymore, now it uses "resolvectl".

*The problem:* I adapted the script trying the two solutions below, but in both cases once vpn.sh successfully connects me to the VPN and executes vpn_routes.sh I'm no longer able to browse the internet (websites don't load, etc).

*Solution 1:* adding a symlink. This blocks access to the internet:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/bin/systemd-resolve
```

*Solution 2:* I tried to adapt the command to resolvectl, but I'm having the same problem:

```
sudo resolvectl dns gxxx 11.xxx.x.xx 22.xxx.x.xxx
sudo resolvectl domain xxxxx.com
```

The command:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --interface gxxx --set-dns 11.xxx.x.xx --set-dns 22.xxx.x.xxx --set-domain xxxxx.com
```

Could someone tell me how this command should be properly adapted to use resolvectl in 22.04?

Thanks in advance!

Complete script (vpn_routes.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

GW=$(route -n | grep gxxx | grep 0.0.0.0 | awk '{print $2}')

echo "Gateway: ${GW}"

sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 dev gxxx
sudo route add -net xx.x.xx.x gw ${GW} netmask 255.255.254.0 dev gxxx
sudo route add -net xx.x.xx.0 gw ${GW} netmask 255.255.254.0 dev gxxx

sudo systemd-resolve --interface gxxx --set-dns 11.xxx.x.xx --set-dns 22.xxx.x.xxx --set-domain xxxxx.com
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the output of the commands ip a, ip route and resolvectl status (It's modified for security reasons):

COMMAND >>> ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu xxx qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/XXX scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlpxxxxx: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu xxx qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.x.x/xx brd xxx.xxx.x.xx scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlpxxxxx
       valid_lft 68xxxsec preferred_lft 68xxxsec
    inet6 2803:xxxx:98c4:xxxx:xxxx:efc5:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 58xxxxsec preferred_lft 6xxxxsec
    inet6 2803:xxxx:xxxx:8853:xxxx:ee6d:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 114xxxxxsec preferred_lft 11xxxxxxsec
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxxx:64d5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: gxxx: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu xxxx xxxx xxxxx state UP group default qlen xxx
    link/none 
    inet 10.xxx.xx.xxx/xx scope global gxxx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.xx.x.x/xx brd 172.xx.xxx.xxx scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: br-xxxxxxxxxxx: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu xxxx qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.xx.x.x/xx brd 172.xx.xxx.xxx scope global br-xxxxxxxxxxx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

COMMAND >>> ip route (sample)

```
default via xxx.xxx.x.x dev wlpxxxxx proto dhcp metric 600 
xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx via xxx.xxx.x.x dev wlpxxxxx 
xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx via xxx.xxx.x.x dev wlpxxxxx 
xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx via xxx.xxx.x.x dev wlpxxxxx 
xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx dev wlpxxxxx scope link metric 1000 
172.xx.x.x/xx dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.xx.x.x/xx dev br-xxxxxxxxxxx proto kernel scope link src 172.xx.x.x linkdown 
xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx dev wlpxxxxx proto kernel scope link src xxx.xxx.xx.x metric 600 
xxx.xxx.xx.x/xx via xxx.xxx.x.x dev wlpxxxxx 
xxx.xxx.xx.x/xx via xxx.xxx.x.x dev wlpxxxxx 
10.x.xx.x/xx via 10.xxx.xx.xxx  dev gpd0 
10.x.xx.x/xx via 10.xxx.xx.xxx  dev gpd0 
10.xx.x.x/xx via 10.xxx.xx.xxx  dev gpd0
```

---

COMMAND >>> resolvectl status

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 11.xxx.x.xx
       DNS Servers: 11.xxx.x.xxx 22.xxx.x.xxx
        DNS Domain: xxxxx.com

Link 2 (wlpxxxxx)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: xxx.xxx.x.x fexxxxxxxxxx

Link 3 (gxxx)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 11.xxx.x.xxx
       DNS Servers: 11.xxx.x.xxx 22.xxx.x.xxx
        DNS Domain: xxxxx.com

Link 4 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 27 (br-xxxxxxxxxxx)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

Comment: You don’t specifically say what the problem or error is, just that you’re having a problem with the command `systemd-resolve`. Please add any error messages to your question. So how is this script intended to be used? Once? At every boot? Something else? The commands you’ve entered using `resolvectl` look correct. After entering on command line, look at `resolvectl status` and you should see the changes. But these changes will not persist a reboot.

Comment: You might start with the man page, man resolvectl, to see the current switches and the way they should be used.  systemd-resolve was dropped as probably too confusing (mixed up with systemd-resolved).

Comment: Thanks @mpboden, I updated the question so it's a little bit clearer what the problem is

Comment: After running your scripts and connecting to the VPN, please update your question with output of `ip a`, `ip route`, and `resolvectl status`.

Comment: I added the outputs of the commands @mpboden, at least as much as I could. This time  my Slack got disconnected, but I'm able to browse the internet.

Comment: I’m sorry, but your extreme level of redactions aren’t helping. If the IP addresses are associated with private networks, then there’s no reason to redact as such.